# Kirchoff Current Law using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am wondering how should I implement KCL using JavaScript. I have several current meter that to detect the value of current along a line.

I came out with a simple program but was unable to think about how to implement KCL efficiently.

```
var currentPointsDBA = new Array(); // Data from electricity meter will be captured and store in this array
var totalCurrentMDB = new Array(); // Total current from adding will be stored in array. Each index represents 1 distribution board.
const totalBusBar = 5;

for (z=0; z<currentPointsDBA.length(); z++){
 totalCurrent += currentPoints[z];
}

totalCurrentMDB[0] = totalCurrent;

var currentCheck = [
 {
  name: DBA, number: 0, threshold: 0
 }];

 for(i=0; i<totalBusBar; i++){
  var totalCurrentCheck = currentCheck[i];

  if(totalCurrentMDB[totalCurrentCheck.number] != 0){
 //DO SOMETHING
 }

 }
```

I realized with this, the condition will never be met as I am adding the current without using the concept of current entering the node is equals to current exiting a node.

Another difficulty that I was facing was to have an algorithm that can be used to calculate positively and negatively for KCL.

Inputs would be a power line that will be connected to a transducer(meter to measure current). Output is also current that is connected to a meter.

[image]

For the Point 1,2,3,4,5 it will be replaced with the meters. Basically, I would want an algorithm to have `Sum of DBA = Point 1+2+3+4+5`. However, point 1 is bi-directional. It can act as input or output. The issue will be to figure out how the current direction is and use that to determine as input or output.

Comment: For those of us unfamiliar with KCL, could you add some information on what this algorithm inputs/outputs?  More specifically what your implementation will achieve?

Comment: Edited my OP. This is to come out with a prototype controller that could be used to detect power theft.